# Need some good plugins for Indian Instrument Sounds to be used in Pro Tools

Tags: plugin, pro-tools-9

I am not looking for just free ones but paid ones are fine too. So far I've come across the following two:

swarsystems.com/SwarPlug/
swarsystems.com/SwarGroove/

A good deal for both at http://www.sudeepaudio.com/store/swarsystems/swarplug3withswargroove

I amazed that I can't seem to find anything else. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there's always Native Instruments Discovery Series: India
https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/orchestral-cinematic/india/

Comment: Thanks, this is a good option. However, after doing some research I found out that it supports only VST plugins whereas my Pro Tools 9 doesn't support VST. So SwarGroove seems like a good deal considering the number of instruments, plugin format support and pricing.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum Leap [Silk](http://www.soundsonline.com/Silk) has multi-sampled ethnic instruments original from India like Dilruba, Sarod, Tanpura and Bansuri along other great virtual instruments. The next best virtual instrument library for east west for ethnics would be [Ra](http://www.soundsonline.com/Ra).

From having used both and a couple of other kontakt instruments - I can say that there's a good chance to get the sound you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much. very interesting, this never came up in my search results. I am planning of purchasing the SwarGroove considering the pricing and the included number of instruments. Next best comes NI, again based on the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Pro Tools is historically bad for this type of thing. You want to consider switching DAWs if your a composer.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations? Studio One?

Comment: Composers musicians almost always favor Logic it has  great virtual instruments of course you need to be a Mac user. Or Cubase. Musicians notoriously hate Pro Tools as midi has always been it's achilles heal.

Comment: If your not doing any audio recording and working in the box then a midi sequencer such as Reason or FL studio could be an option. Though I would keep audio editing as an option. Pro Tools is geared toward professional audio recording editing and mixing and is a poor choice if all you want to do is write and compose.